# Java Google Alert API

Tags: java, alert

Google does not provide any API for Google Alert create, update, list, delete operations. I need to build java application to manage the alerts with create, update, list, delete operations through program.

I have done some research in the internet and tried to put across the code in Java but does not seem to be working.

Approach Taken - Client Login into Google (works) and then Http Post to create alert (does not work), and then parse html to comprehend the list of alerts (this can be made to work - not coded yet)

I know there are few solution on the web for a fee. However I do not want to rely on other's closed source.

Any solution will be of great help

Answer (score 0):

You can find a java library for creating, listing and deleting google alerts here: http://www.coders11.com/googlealertsapi/index.php

It works perfectly, the only problem is that it became commercial.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this API, that is java library.

https://github.com/nnhiti/google-alert-api

Comment: the sources are not included